# Remove hyperlink from shortcode

Tags: php, css, wordpress

Apologies for the novice question; I am new to Wordpress and PHP.

I've been using the following:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[shortcode]')?>
```

to display a shortcode. My problem, however, is that, as the icons act as pointers to other webpages or protocols (like email), they are displayed as an icon with an underline beneath them.

I still want them to point to somewhere but I don't want the underline to be visible. Looking in the CSS files for the plugin itself, it does have

```
text-decoration: none;
```

but this doesn't seem to affect anything. Wordpress also states that the stylesheet for the plugin is inactive. I'm not quite sure how to add a class to this effect for the anchor on the primary stylesheet (i.e. for the webpage itself) but I was hoping that would be the solution.

Comment: What theme/plugin are we looking at here?

Comment: The theme is Readly. The git link is available [here](https://github.com/wpshower/Readly) if that helps. I just tried doing it the other way around too: `wp_enqueue_style` on the php for the plugin and then adding `text-decoration: none` to the `a img` class but it still doesn't work. Also, the plugin is OSD Social Media Sharing and the git is available [here](https://github.com/wp-plugins/osd-social-media-sharing).

Comment: try to change text-decoration with : cursor: crosshair;

Comment: Didn't work unfortunately. Also, not sure if I misunderstood you, but I require the underline to be permanently invisible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
text-decoration: none !important;
```

you need to use this css for a, a:active, a:hover, a:focus links class.

Comment: Added the above to those classes (although in my stylesheet, active, hover and focus are under 'Reset' and a alone is under 'Links'). Refreshing the page yields no change. Do I need to add [wp_enqueue_style](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style) to the php file of the plugin?

Comment: Check by view source that the stylesheet that you have write css is applying or is available there if yes than no need else you have to register and enqueue style in page.